# Regression query

Tags: regression, non-linear-regression, eviews

I am new to using Eviews. I want to fit my data to an exponential curve: y = a*e^(bx). I am running the regression using these two equations:

1. `MICE_1= COEF(1)*(EXP(COEF(2)*OBSERVATION))`
2. `LOG(MICE_1) = COEF(3) + COEF(4)*OBSERVATION`

Since, both equations are the same, coef(2)=coef(4) and coef(1)= exp(coef(3))

However, I am getting different coefficients using the two equations. Can someone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: I think this is because the curve fitting software is minimizing something different in each case. In case 1, the error being minimized is "f1(observation) - mice_1". In case 2, the error is "f2(observation) - log(mice_1)". The second case is minimizing error based on the log of mice_1.

Comment: Okay, got it. If I plot my data in excel and go for an exponential trendline, the equation I get has the same coefficients I get from eqn. 2 here. That means excel is taking the log to find coefficients. Can we say that eqn1 is exponential non-linear regression method and eqn2 is exponential linear regression method? Does that make sense?